# C# replace a certain type of character in a string

Tags: c#, string, replace

Let's say I've got a string with the value of "C4".
In my code I generate some number, let's say it's 200, and now I want my string to look like this: "C200". Of course that nothing is known at compile time.

Is it possible to do this change with a single elegant line? I know this line I will write is not syntactically correct but this is the idea I'm looking for:

```
newString = oldString.Replace(typeof (int), newNumber.ToString());
```

Comment: Have you considered using regex?

Comment: What is your pattern of replacement? Will it always be an upper case `C` followed by a number?

Comment: could you show me an example of what you had in mind?

Comment: @Renan the strings are actually excel cells so it will always be some letters and then some numbers

Comment: it looks like he wants to replace integer with the new number from his code

Answer (score 5):

You can use regular expression:

```
newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, @"\d+", newNumber.ToString());
```

Comment: @YonatanNir - Instead of asking if it will work, test it!  Don't just take the answer and use it, learn about RegEx and understand how it works!

Comment: @YonatanNir `\d` means digit 0..9. Symbol `+` means one or more. Whole patterns searches for one or more consecutive digits in your string and replaces found matches with new number

Comment: @ChrisDunaway nobody asked if it works... don't just comment nonsense

Comment: @YonatanNir - I see you deleted your comment where you asked if it would work, thus making both my and Jonesy's comments seem like "nonsense".